# Ocultar parte da legenda de um gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um gráfico feito com `ggplot2`, na legenda está aparecendo um `size` e eu gostaria de retirá-lo, mas não sei como.

Meu código:

```
updates %>%
    mutate(mortalidade = deaths / confirmed) %>%
    filter(iso3c %in% paises, date == max(date) - 1) %>%
    arrange(desc(mortalidade)) %>%
    select(country, mortalidade, region) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(country, - mortalidade), y = mortalidade, fill = na.omit(region))) +
    geom_text(aes(x = country, y = mortalidade, label =  percent(round(mortalidade, 2)),
              vjust = -0.15, size = 3)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
    scale_fill_economist() +
    labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray", linetype = "solid"))
```

Meu gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de retirar esse `size A3`. Se acharem necessário, coloco o `dput()` dos meus dados.

Comment: Outros usuários devem ser capazes de copiar e rodar o código que postou sem precisar solicitar dados extras. Se não está usando uma base de dados do R, sempre inclua os dados usados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ggplot inclui nas legendas todas as variáveis especificadas dentro das estéticas (exceto os eixos). Se o valor usado para alguma forma (no seu caso, tamanho do texto) é constante ou independente de alguma variável do seu conjunto de dados, coloque-o fora da `aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dados <- diamonds[1:4,]

ggplot(dados, aes(clarity, table)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = cut)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = carat), size = 4, nudge_y = 3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisa mapear uma variável para uma geometria mas não quer que seja exibida na legenda, use a opção `show.legend = FALSE`. Por exemplo:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(clarity, table)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = cut), show.legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Outra opção é retirar `vjust = -0.15, size = 3` do `aes()`. Como não dependem de variáveis da base não são necessários ali e deixam de ter uma legenda própria.

Comment: Sim, é o que pretendia demonstrar, só que usando um exemplo genérico.